# How to different object do not fall apart in blender soft body?

Tags: physics, soft-body

I have a model of Minecraft wolf, which I wanted to fall down like a soft body. But, it has inner 7 parts, how can I join them to make a ballon soft body simulation[image]? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You can delete the intersecting faces and join the objects with the Bridge Edge Loops tool. If you want to join one face with multiple others like the chest and the legs you have to subdivide the chest.

Comment: Thanks, but too less vertices, also it is unwrapped very tightly, so in this case this method won't be useful much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's gonna solve your problem but try selecting all the differents parts and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join them togheter into a single mesh.

Comment: Thanks, I have been tried, no result.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This solution can be useful, if mesh has a higher amount of vertices, that do not intersect much.